# Skyrim SE loads forever after pressing Play

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I open the launcher and it's fine, then I click Play and the Bethesda logo plays and the music is fine, but when it gets to the main menu there are no buttons such as Continue or New. There is just a loading symbol. Can anyone help? I'm playing on PC.

Thanks.

Comment: are you playing on console or PC?

Comment: @ZeroStack I want to say it's PC, since the OP mentions the launcher, but you're right, we can't do much until we know ;)

Comment: Do you actually mean "forever", meaning that it has never loaded, or do you mean it just takes a long time?

Comment: forever forever

Answer (score -2):

Nevermind, there was something in the data folder that I had to get rid of. It works fine now!

Comment: What did you get rid of?

Comment: My attempt at making a mod from a long time ago that I forgot was there.